# Is there way to know that fraction is actually whole number?

Tags: java, numbers, fractions

I use Fraction from apache library

```
 Fraction fraction = Fraction.getFraction(0, 7, 13);
 fraction = fraction.multiplyBy(Fraction.getFraction(26));
 System.out.print(fraction.getProperWhole());
```

this code returns 14 - it is expected result

```
 Fraction fraction = Fraction.getFraction(0, 7, 13);
 fraction = fraction.multiplyBy(Fraction.getFraction(27));
 System.out.print(fraction.getProperWhole());
```

It outs 14 too but actually it is not exact 14

Is there way to know that fraction is actually whole number

Comment: Well what is the `Fraction` class? That's not a standard Java class, so we don't know what functionality it provides.

Comment: @JonSkeet from the *"I use Fraction from apache library"*, it seems it is https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/Fraction.html

Comment: And it looks like getReducedFraction would answer that: if the fraction can be reduced to an integer, the denominator would be 1

Comment: @DenysSéguret: From which comment?

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited my comment to clarify

Comment: Ah, right. Yes, that makes sense. I suggest that if the OP is actually using that library (which does seem likely) that they edit their question to link to it.

Comment: For a fraction of the form x / y, it's a whole number if, and only if, x % y is 0. I imagine that a 3rd party fraction library would have a function that exploits this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using `org.apache.commons.lang.math.Fraction`.  This has a `getProperNumerator` method which returns `0` if and only if the fraction is equal to an integer.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the apache documentation you will see this

> getProperWhole
>
> public int getProperWhole() Gets the proper whole part of the
>   fraction.
>
> An improper fraction 7/4 can be resolved into a proper one, 1 3/4.
>   This method returns the 1 from the proper fraction.
>
> If the fraction is negative such as -7/4, it can be resolved into -1
>   3/4, so this method returns the positive whole part -1.
>
> Returns: the whole fraction part of a proper fraction, that includes
>   the sign

So, your result is the expected one.

If you want to know if the fraction is a whole number.
You can do something like this :

```
f.getNumerator() % f.getDenominator() == 0 ? true : false
```

Since a rounded fraction as its numerator to by a multiple of the denominator.

As an alternative, you can also reduce the fraction with `f.reduce()` then check that the denominator is equals to one.

Source : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/Fraction.html#getProperWhole()

Comment: @gstackoverflow could you explain what your issue is in more detail then as it appears to be what you need, the way I read it.

Comment: What about fraction.reduce() and then check that fraction.getDenoninator() == 1

Comment: Could work as well, I don't know the implementation of reduce, but I expect this to be slightly faster. In any case, reduce then check the denominator to be equals to 1 would works as well

Comment: @gstackoverflow I updated my answer, that will give you the way to check that the fraction is a whole number or not